# Why it is true for rapid decreasing function $g$ that: $\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|x|^{l\geq 0}|g^{(k\geq 0)}(x-y)|\leq A_{l,k}(1+|y|)^{l}$

Tags: calculus, inequality, fourier-analysis, schwartz-space

If $g$ is of rapid decrease, that is $\displaystyle\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|x|^{l\geq 0}|g^{(k\geq 0)}(x)|<\infty$, then we have: $$\displaystyle\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|x|^{l\geq 0}|g^{(k\geq 0)}(x-y)|\leq A_{l,k}(1+|y|)^{l}$$
where $A_{l,k}\geq 0$ is a constant dependent on $l,k$.

How can I induce the above inequality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** You may observe that
$$
\begin{align}
(1+|x|^2)^{l}|g^{(k)}(x-y)|&=(1+|x-y|^2)^{l}|g^{(k)}(x-y)|\frac{(1+|x|^2)^{l}}{(1+|x-y|^2)^{l}}\\
&\leq a_{l,k}\:(1+|y|^2)^{l}
\end{align}
$$ where we have used [Peetre's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peetre%27s_inequality), whose proof may be found [here](http://planetmath.org/peetresinequality).

Comment: Would you please tell me how to eliminate the square on $|y|$ in the last term? I tried to bound by $(1+|x|)^{l}|g^{k}(x-y)|$ instead of  $(1+|x|^{2})^{l}|g^{k}(x-y)|$, but in this case, I cannot apply Peetre's inequality.